# multiple action for one submit button cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

is it possible to have a button that calls two different actions in two different controllers in a cakephp application? For example, let's say that I have a text box on a page and a next button, when I click the next button I want the data entered into the text box to be saved to the database and move to the next page (the moving to another page is another controller action)

Is this possible?

Let me know, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is totally wrong thought. There are different approaches but your "two buttons" is totally miss-leading. I guess because you did not understand the MVC design pattern, read about it.

When you submit your form from, lets call it /reports/step1 and the data validates simply save it and redirect to /reports/step2.

Different forms that do different things should be always separated. If you start to do multiple things in the same action and view things become messy for sure. Simply go for best practice techniques: If a method is doing two things at once refactor it.